# Why does Grails not recognize BuildStandalone?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails app (2.3.6) that uses the [Grails Build Standalone plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/standalone).

The `myapp/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
    runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:gson:1.1.4'
    compile ":standalone:1.2.3"
    build ":release:3.0.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.0.4"
}
```

When I go to `myapp` and run `grails build-standalone myapp.jar --tomcat` I get:

```
$ grails build-standalone myapp.jar --tomcat
|Loading Grails 2.3.6
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
|Script 'BuildStandalone' not found, did you mean:
    1) InstallDependency
    2) Stats
    3) CreateMultiProjectBuild_
    4) TestApp
    5) InstallPlugin
Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Did you compile the app once after adding the plugin? either by refresh-dependencies or grails compile.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro this worked (doing a `grails compile`) - can I ask **why?** To the best of my knowledge the use of the Standalone plugin was introduced months ago and has never changed. It was just today that this issue cropped up.

Comment: If `.grails` was cleared somehow then you would see this types of issue. It is always a recommended practice to clean and compile the app in those scenarios.